# Is there any way to log all data emitted by an iPhone over a day?

Tags: ios, iphone, networking

This is for a visualisation project on what data gets recorded about us from our phones.

The idea would be to log as much detail as is reasonable to an internal location (probably) on the phone for later analysis, e.g. HTTP requests. It doesn’t need to be secret at all – the subject will be aware they are participating – and it doesn’t have to be 100% automatic; if the phone owner needs to perform some action regularly that’s okay too, although they need to be able to use their phone approximately normally throughout the day.

I can’t find any Apple APIs that look suitable, but that’s hardly surprising. I can find some approaches that would potentially work on OSX (tcpdump, netstat), so perhaps a jailbroken iOS device would support one of those?

Alternatively, running a custom proxy server would open up a bunch more options, but is there any way to get a mobile device to reliably route through a proxy server?

Answer (score 0):

It appears this question provides a viable proxy-server-based approach:

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/81102/proxy-settings-for-iphone-3g-connection

Basically, it seems it *is* possible to route all requests through a proxy server, even over cellular.

Comment: I’m not going to mark this as the accepted answer unless I actually get it working. Other approaches welcome!